# How to install mongodb-odm on symfony4 with php 7.3 (Windows 10)?

Tags: mongodb, symfony4, doctrine-odm, php-7.3

I am trying to install mongodb-odm on symfony4 (php 7.3), but getting those problems

```
  Problem 1
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.5 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.4 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.3 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm ^2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5].
```

When I try to install `composer require mongodb/mongodb` I'm getting

```
 Problem 1
- Installation request for mongodb/mongodb ^1.6 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.6.0].
- mongodb/mongodb 1.6.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.7 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
```

I see in phpinfo(); that mongodb is installed (MongoDB extension version 1.7.2), but when I type php -m, I don't see mongo there.

Comment: maybe you have enabled the extension in web-context and haven't in cli?

Comment: @malarzm When you enable MongoDB in php.ini, such a case shouldn't have a place. I found the cause :) I had in environment variables added a correct path to php 7.3.5 (from wamp dir), on my wamp server I was using the same version, but when I edit php.ini from wamp, they took some php.ini from another path :(